# Custom boot confidence intervals with lme4

Tags: r, lme4, confidence-interval

I want to calculate bootstrap confidence intervals with `lme4`. This is my code (data in code comment):

```
library(lme4)


# data from: https://github.com/bbolker/mixedmodels-misc/blob/master/data/culcita.RData
load("d:/del/1/culcita.RData")

cmod_mod <- glmer(predation~ttt+(1|block),data=culcita_dat,
                     family=binomial)

cmod_mod_CI_profile_95<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.95, method = "profile")
cmod_mod_CI_profile_85<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.85, method = "profile")
cmod_mod_CI_profile_75<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.75, method = "profile")

cmod_mod_CI_Wald_95<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.95, method = "Wald")
cmod_mod_CI_Wald_85<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.85, method = "Wald")
cmod_mod_CI_Wald_75<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.75, method = "Wald")

cmod_mod_CI_boot_95<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.95, method = "boot")
cmod_mod_CI_boot_85<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.85, method = "boot")
cmod_mod_CI_boot_75<-confint(cmod_mod, level = 0.75, method = "boot")
```

It gives some warnings and even errors but I think those are not important in this context. The main problem is that `Wald` and `profile` methods confidence intervals are estimated to CI `0.95`, `0.85`, `0.75` as indicated in `level` parameter,  but with `boot` method it only estimates `0.95` CI, no matter what I put in `level` parameter.

Another example without error and very few warnings, but takes much more time to compute and same problem with `boot` persists:

```
library(lme4)

hdp <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hdp.csv")
hdp <- within(hdp, {
  Married <- factor(Married, levels = 0:1, labels = c("no", "yes"))
  DID <- factor(DID)
  HID <- factor(HID)
})

m <- glmer(remission ~ IL6 +
             (1 | DID), data = hdp, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),
           nAGQ = 10)

m_mod_CI_profile_95<-confint(m, level = 0.95, method = "profile")
m_mod_CI_profile_85<-confint(m, level = 0.85, method = "profile")
m_mod_CI_profile_75<-confint(m, level = 0.75, method = "profile")

m_mod_CI_Wald_95<-confint(m, level = 0.95, method = "Wald")
m_mod_CI_Wald_85<-confint(m, level = 0.85, method = "Wald")
m_mod_CI_Wald_75<-confint(m, level = 0.75, method = "Wald")

m_mod_CI_boot_95<-confint(m, level = 0.95, method = "boot")
m_mod_CI_boot_85<-confint(m, level = 0.85, method = "boot")
m_mod_CI_boot_75<-confint(m, level = 0.75, method = "boot")
```

**Questions:**

1. Why `confint()` with `level` parameter value other than `0.95` does not gives me CI that I am indicating and gives  `0.95` CI?
2. How to get CI with `boot` method other than `0.95`?

Comment: With `method = "boot"` the level is not passed to the boot function. You can see the code with `getAnywhere('confint.merMod')`. The relevant code line is near the end: `bb <- bootMer(object, FUN = FUN, nsim = nsim, ...)`. And function `getAnywhere('bootMer')` does not have a `level` argument.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I see. Here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf on p.9 no `level` parameter too.